# Replacing Specific URL in the Same Class

Tags: jquery, replace

I plan to change the default picture of their account profile on my blog with jQuery. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".avatar-image-container img").attr("src") == "http://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif") {
    $(".avatar-image-container img").attr("src", "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fMGj0xxU17A/VzwRIi8g6DI/AAAAAAAAFLo/qhnNcpj4eq0oIo3pW0zAeuKLvLXiRKLsACLcB/s1600/no-photo.jpg");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avatar-image-container">
  <img src="http://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif" />
</div>

<div class="avatar-image-container">
  <img src="http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-52PXwUPvjcQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAPA/LsFtU011abs/s80-c/photo.jpg" />
</div>
```

If you use this code, all URLs replaceable. Well how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter only elements that matches src to specified url and then set the new attribute to them:

**Solution 1:**

Using `.filter()` function:

```
$(".avatar-image-container img").filter(function(){
 return $(this).attr("src")=="http://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif";
}).attr("src", "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fMGj0xxU17A/VzwRIi8g6DI/AAAAAAAAFLo/qhnNcpj4eq0oIo3pW0zAeuKLvLXiRKLsACLcB/s1600/no-photo.jpg");
```

**Solution 2:**

Using Attribute equals selector:

```
$(".avatar-image-container img[src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif']").attr("src", "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fMGj0xxU17A/VzwRIi8g6DI/AAAAAAAAFLo/qhnNcpj4eq0oIo3pW0zAeuKLvLXiRKLsACLcB/s1600/no-photo.jpg");
```